# Как вычислить максимально возможную длину шага?

Tags: c#, строки

У меня есть задача перемешать ключ и текст с определенным шагом:

```
Дано:
string text = "abcde"
string key = "123"

Результат:
string result = "1ab2cd3e" // в этом примере максимальный шаг = 2
```

Можно ли как-то определить максимальный шаг с помощью переменных text и key?

Comment: `(text.length + 1) / key.length`

Comment: @slippyk этот вариант я использую сейчас, но он работает не во всех случаях

Comment: `(text.length/key.length - 0,5) < (int) step < (text.length/key.length + 0,5)`

Comment: @Akina, `0,5`? o_O

Comment: @Qwertiy А что удивляет? Решением является шаг, при котором длина последней группы находится в диапазоне от 0,5 до 1,5 шага.

Comment: @Akina: 1. Запятая вместо точки. 2. Дробные числа, когда всё (и входные данные, и результат) целочисленные.

Comment: @Qwertiy 1. Локаль у меня такая - ничем не могу помочь :) 2) Меж этих двух дробных границ надо найти единственное целое число (на это как бы намекает вставка типа *int*) - оно и будет решением.

Comment: @Akina, код от локали не зависит, а формула с половинками может быть неверной.

Comment: Где тут код? просто выражение для вычисления границ... *формула с половинками может быть неверной* Точная метода выглядит так: найти целое N такое, что выполняется условие `text.length - N * key.length BETWEEN N*0.5 AND N*1.5`. Это если я верно понял требование равномерности смешивания. Если же требуется минимизировать длину последней группы - то решением будет тривиальное целочисленное деление, и не стоило вопрос задавать. PS. Предполагается, что длина текста заведомо больше длины ключа...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по всему, нужное число равно `text.Length / (key.Length - 1)`.

---

Пусть `text.Length` = *t*, `key.Length` = *k*.

Пусть искомое число *x*, тогда у нас за каждым символом ключа, кроме последнего, обязано находиться *x* символов текста. Это значит, что длина текста как минимум (*k* − 1)*x*.

*t* ⩾ (*k* − 1)*x*, *x* ⩽ *t* / (*k* − 1).

Поскольку *x* — целое число, то вместо точного частного *t* / (*k* − 1) можно взять остаток от целочисленного деления.

Равенство достигается для распределения, в котором за последним символом ключа ничего нет.

Comment: почему `x(k-1)`? Я так понял, нам надо весь ключ засунуть в текст, тогда же будет `xk`?

Comment: @tym32167: Исходя из примера ТС, для текста `"abcdef"` и ключа `"123"` лучшим вариантом является `"1abc2def3"`, а не `"1ab2cd3ef"` (оба валидны), т. к. нам нужно максимальное число _x_.

Comment: а, я понял, -1 - чтобы расположить последний символ ключа в конце.

Comment: @tym32167: Именно так. Ну или как можно дальше.